# How to add plugins to the WordPress repository?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to add my plugin to the WordPress Repository so that users can just search for on the admin panel and then install.

I've filled the plugin form from wordpress.org with a title, description and I don`t know which URL I need to provide.

This URL can be from GITHUB with the files? Or something else?

Also, I need to know how long takes to the approval? Approximately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a url. The url is if you already have a page on your site that tells them about the plugin.

Approval can take anywhere from 24 hours to a week. In my experience, it's usually within 48 hours.

Comment: But, they need just a description? The aproval do not depend on the plugin content and the code?

Comment: No it doesn't. You can even leave the URL blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the plugin directory, upload it to your server and provide the url in the field.

After submission it will take one or two days to get access to the directory.

Files are pushed to the directory using svn.

**Steps to publish plugin in wordpress directory**

1. Requesting repository access
2. Setup Repository
3. Submitting changes to the repository

Check this tutorial for detailed instructions - http://mobapper.com/blog/publish-plugin-wordpress-plugin-repository/